# Having trouble posting to express backend with Axios w/ React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, next.js

I am using React, and Nextjs with a Express back-end running on port 3001.

I am trying to get my sign up page to post the info to the database, 
but I am getting a set of errors

EDIT - FIXED CORS ISSUE, Still having issues posting to DB

EDIT - THIS IS THE NEW ERROR:

```
POST http://localhost:3001/users/signup 404 (Not Found)
```

This Uncaught promise error:

```
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:83)
```

I thought the issue was with the axios post, but I am not sure. 
Because I already have Cors enabled, and in the headers for axios options too, I am not sure what the issue is..

BACKEND :

app.js :

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const logger = require("morgan");
const session = require("express-session");
const FileStore = require("session-file-store")(session);
const upload = require("express-fileupload");

app.use(upload());
console.log("Server Started!");

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});

app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(cors);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
  session({
    resave: false,
    secret: "hello",
    saveUninitialized: true,
    is_logged_in: false,
  })
);

const indexRouter = require("./routes/index");
app.use("/", indexRouter);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('<h1>hello world</h1>')
});

module.exports = app;
```

I am not sure what else you would need out of the backend, all routes and stuff are handled with nextjs. 
FRONTEND:

SignUp.jsx :

```
import React from "react";
import { Component } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import {signup} from "./userFunctions";

class Signup extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      username: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
      query: "",
      hits: [],
    };
    this.onChangeUsername = this.onChangeUsername.bind(this);
    this.onChangeEmail = this.onChangeEmail.bind(this);
    this.onChangePassword = this.onChangePassword.bind(this);
    this.onChangeQuery = this.onChangeQuery.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onChangeUsername = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      username: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  onChangeEmail = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      email: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  onChangePassword = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      password: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  onChangeQuery = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      query: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("hello")

    const newUser = {
      username: this.state.username,
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password,
      query: this.state.query
    };


    signup(newUser).then((res) => {
      res.redirect("/chat");
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Wrapper>
        <TitleWrapper>
          <SignUpTitle>Signup</SignUpTitle>
        </TitleWrapper>
        <FormWrapper>
          <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <HThree>E-mail:</HThree>
          <EmailInput
            type="text"
            placeholder="E-mail"
            onChange={this.onChangeEmail}
            value={this.state.email}
          ></EmailInput>
          <HThree>Username:</HThree>
          <UsernameInput
            type="text"
            placeholder="Username"
            onChange={this.onChangeUsername}
            value={this.state.username}
          ></UsernameInput>
          <br></br>
          <HThree>Password:</HThree>
          <PasswordInput
            type="text"
            placeholder="Password"
            onChange={this.onChangePassword}
            value={this.state.password}
          ></PasswordInput>
          <br></br>
          <HThree>Confirm Password:</HThree>
          <PasswordMatchInput
            type="text"
            placeholder="Password-Confirm"
            onChange={this.onChangePassword}
            value={this.state.password}
          ></PasswordMatchInput>
          <br></br>
          <SignUpButton
            type="submit"
            value="Signup"
            className="signup-button"
          ></SignUpButton>
          </form>
          <br></br>
          <LoginPage href="/login">Looking for login?</LoginPage>
        </FormWrapper>
      </Wrapper>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the post statements

userFunctions.js :

```
import axios from "axios";



const options = {
    credentials: "include",
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT"
    },

};

export const signup = (newUser) => {
    return axios
        .post("http://localhost:3001/users/signup", {
            name: newUser.name,
            email: newUser.email,
            password: newUser.password
        }, options)



.then(response => {
        console.log("User is now registered")
    })
```

}

Comment: In your `axios.post`, add `http://` to the url.

Comment: Updated Post to fix issues now

Comment: We need to see `routes/index.js`, the route that is handling the request. (and you can remove SignUp.jsx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cors` is a factory function which when called returns the Express middleware function which sets the required CORS headers which allow incoming cross origin requests.

```
app.use(cors()); // instead of app.use(cors)
```

[Link to Documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#usage)

Also in `axios` you must prefix your endpoint URL with the protocol part.

```
.post("http://localhost:3001/users/signup") // you were missing "http://"
```

Comment: Remove your custom CORS middleware (the code before actually using the `cors` module) and apply my changes. It should work. You're missing the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` anyway and that's why your request fails.

Comment: Changed it to what you had said, and nothing changed still the same error.

Comment: Removed my first comment because I had mis-read what you had said, but then I went back and do what you had said and removed the custom headers.

Comment: Also I found another error - your POST URL is incorrect because it doesn't include the protocol part.

Comment: What do you mean include the protocol part?

Comment: Your URL: `localhost:3001/users/signup`, expected URL: `http://localhost:3001/users/signup`. The missing part is "http://" which indicates to the browser that the request is using the HTTP protocol.

Comment: Okay awesome that fixed the cors issue, and a new error saying posting to that page 404s

Comment: That simply means that there is no route matching your request. You haven't declared a POST method handler for that address in your Express router.